# Difference between Groovy String variable replacement

Tags: string, groovy

When looking at examples of variable substitution in GStrings, I have noticed two difference syntaxes.  This can be seen here: [Groovy Templates](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates)

This has the example:

```
def text = 'Dear "$firstname $lastname",\nSo nice to meet you in <% print city %>.\nSee you in ${month},\n${signed}'
```

It looks like ${variable} is used more commonly when you have an expression, but $variable is used when you just have a single variable, but even here they mix it with $firstname and ${month}.  Is there a reason to do it one way or another when you have a single variable and not an expression, or does it not matter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't matter...

As you say, if you have an expression like `"${name.toUpperCase()}"`, `"${number}th"` or `"${list[0]}"`, then it has to be inside braces, but both `"${name}"` and `"$name"` are the same.

Indeed, so long as it's simple property access you can omit the braces, ie: `"Hello $person.username"`

It could be said that adding the braces can make your string templates easier to read, but that's a personal preference thing.